# Is it best to call a method (from class A) in a class (class B) which then calls a method in a class (C) or to use a getter for Class C in Class B?

Tags: java, coding-style, getter, composition

E.g.

In Class A:

```
b.doThing();
```

In Class B:

```
doThing() {
    c.doThing();
}
```

OR

In class A:

```
b.getClassC().doThing();
```

What is the convention for a situation like this?

Comment: It depends on whether you wish class B to hide its C object. If C is mutable, it might be a good idea to hide it (i.e. not to have a getC() method in B).

Comment: This is overly general, and therefore, you'll get opinion-based answers rather than anything useful. Please present an actual use case, and you might get a better answer.

Comment: The depends whether your goal is performance (use the getter) or if you want maintainability (go with the first way). Like most answers here I advise to got with maintainability because the increase of performance is almost non-existent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), you should go the first way, i.e. only call the method of class B which itself delegates to class C. This way, you reduce dependencies between your classes which is basically a good thing for reusability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it will be the second case unless the implementing class has do to more than executing one line for example setting/checking states or preparing other methods etc.

The big advantage of this is that you don't need to worry about implementation details by calling

```
b.getClassC().doThing();
```

You don't care if `doThing` will change structurally or methodically in which you would supply more parameters or else.

Answer (score 0):

Object orientation is about *getting objects to do things for you*. Hence you're better off asking 'b' to do something, and the fact that it then calls 'c' is hidden from you, and it can be changed in the future trivially. You don't want to ask 'b' for its component objects and then do something with those.